# Quiet or quietly?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

There is a verse from a children's song:

> Sunday,  Monday,  Tuesday, Wednesday,  Thursday, Friday, Saturday – 
>   Seven days are in a week, I like to sing them quiet.

Why is the adjective "quiet" used instead of the adverb "quietly" here?

Comment: Grammar is not important in a song. What important is the rhymes and the syllables count.

Comment: Who or what is the referent of "them"?

Comment: @BillJ: "Them" = the days of the week.

Answer (score 1):

Quiet. 
5. Out of public scrutiny; known or discussed by few:

> wanted to keep the incident quiet until after the election

I think this meaning corresponds to your example.

> I like to sing them quiet (let it be our secret)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: OK. I didn't know the song, and figured it might be a lullaby, in which case the answer below would make sense.

Compare

> She sang the baby *asleep*.

The action of singing put the baby into a state of sleep.

The complement of the verb  is someone or something acted upon and the state that action puts the person or thing into.

> He hammered the nail *flush*.

Comment: Definitely not. The performer does not make the days quiet :)

Comment: In a children's song, you could sing the days quiet, or sing the baby asleep. But not in this one :)